# Оформить в виде класса

Tags: c++

Помогите переделать програмку, чтобы она была оформлена как 3 файла - `main.cpp`, `class.cpp` и `class.h`

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
string getNextToken(istream &in)
{
    char c;
    string ans = "";
    c = in.get();
    while (!isalpha(c) && !in.eof())
    {
        c = in.get();
    }
    while (isalpha(c))
    {
        ans.push_back(tolower(c));
        c = in.get();
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, int> words;
    ifstream fin("123.txt");

    string s;
    string empty = "";
    while ((s = getNextToken(fin)) != empty)
        ++words[s];

    for (map<string, int>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); ++iter)
        cout << iter->first << ' ' << iter->second << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: У вас нет никакого класса. Вынести в отдельный файл можно разве что `getNextToken`...

Comment: Не ну а если сильно переделать? Я вот хз как этот класс добавить, но нужно его добавить чтобы было 3 файла

Comment: Да сделать 3 файла можно и без класса. Просто вы пишете про `class.cpp`, что как бы намекает на какой-то класс... А так - выносите в `class.cpp` определение `getNextToken`, в `class.h` (который включаете в `main.cpp`) ее объявление, и все готово...

Comment: Не, нужно именно с классом. Но я не знаю, что тут можно изменить и сделать как класс

Comment: @ТеньБиара просто перенесите свою ф-цию `getNextToken` в отдельный файл. Ее определение закинте в свой заголовочный. Заголовочный же файл подключите к файлам `*.cpp` - вот и все.

Comment: !in.eof()  == true   всегда,  это лишнее в условии